# fhir-net-api (STU3) - Hl7.Fhir.Model.PlanDefinition parsing error

Tags: hl7-fhir

Using HL7.FHIR.STU3.Core, I am getting an invalid cast exception when I try and parse an PlanDefinition FHIR file.

> Do I need to set the Schema for PlanDefinition  file?

```
        string HL7FilePath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ANA3.xml");
        string HL7FileData = File.ReadAllText(HL7FilePath)

        var b = new FhirXmlParser().Parse<Bundle>(HL7FileData);
```

Error

```
InValidCastException {"Unable to cast object of type 'Hl7.Fhir.Model.PlanDefinition' to type 'Hl7.Fhir.Model.Bundle'."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse a PlanDefinition resource into a Bundle object, as the InvalidCastException tells you. If you change the `Parse<Bundle>` into `Parse<PlanDefinition>` your code should work fine.